# Objective C equivalent to Java's ArrayList

Tags: java, objective-c, arraylist, equivalent

Just wondering if there is an equivalent to Java's ArrayList in Objective-C?

Or something that can be used to store objects/data that does not have a set size.

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As others have pointed out, [NSArray](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Fmac%2Flibrary%2Fdocumentation%2FCocoa%2FReference%2FFoundation%2FClasses%2FNSArray_Class%2F&ei=vmNQTKPNGYrksQPT6e3tBw&usg=AFQjCNEzJ9rtBpHzcPdYtcF4-uSPmMwMOA&sig2=sg__T95iAO-8PbYyLihR1g)/[NSMutableArray](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Fmac%2Flibrary%2Fdocumentation%2FCocoa%2FReference%2FFoundation%2FClasses%2FNSMutableArray_Class%2F&ei=wmNQTN3RDon2tgOq-5y7Bw&usg=AFQjCNGp5yHi6aVlyr3qT4lHNOWJR0aRew&sig2=XJFMSmZRN-Dq-OMv4dQK0g) are what you're looking for.

Coming from the Java world, you may find that Cocoa's collection offerings feel quite paltry. In fact, the functionality is quite extensive. The `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, and `NSSet` are, in fact, [class clusters](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW34), meaning that the public API is an "abstract" class. When you initialize one of the collections, what you get back is, in fact, a concrete implementation tailored for the data you provide. These implementations can also change the concrete implementation at run time if the data changes (e.g. it grows in size). This is all possible due to Objective-C's much more dynamic run time than Java's static typing (and security) will allow. The class cluster strategy thus hides many of the implementations of, e.g. the `java.util.List` interface, behind a single API.

The Cocoa frameworks are somewhat limited in compound data structures (i.e. those built on top of "primitive" arrays, sets, and dictionaries). You may find that the excellent, open source [CHDataStructures](http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/code/CHDataStructures) fills in many of the gaps.

Comment: I'm searching for the same thing as Julio and seeing a lot of answers that say "just close your eyes and use NS\*Array...". But often you really do want to explicitly use a linked list, e.g. for constant time insertion / deletion of any item (NS\*Array doesn't guarantee this). Choosing the right data structure based on your known access pattern is fundamental to performance. As a newcomer to iOS development I don't understand why Cocoa seems to take away this decision from the programmer?

Answer (score 15):

[`NSMutableArray`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You can add objects to it as needed.